# Got this batch to list filenames with path for files gtr than some size.. How to modify to list only filenames without path and extension?

Tags: batch-file

%unit% and %dsize% would be defined before the batch reaches this point. May be as something like:

```
set "unit=mb"&set "dsize=100"
```

Now is there a way to list only file name? If possible, can anyone tell me how this works? I didn't understand the "set size=%1" and "echo.%~2" part. How does "%~2" echo the file names with path?

```
for /r %%m in (%ext%) do call :logic %%~zm "%%m"
exit
:logic
set size=%1
if '%unit%'=='bb' set "sizen=%size%"
if '%unit%'=='kb' set "sizen=%size:~0,-3%"
if '%unit%'=='mb' set "sizen=%size:~0,-6%"
if not defined sizen set sizen=0
if %sizen% gtr %dsize% echo.%~2>> temp.txt&cls
exit /b
```

Comment: Use `%~n2` instead of `%~2`; type `call /?` for more info...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r %%i in (*.*) do (
echo %%~xxx )
```

Here is your options (to replace my xxx in example)

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
%~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
%~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
%~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable for %I and expands to the
               drive letter and path of the first one found.
%~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation, and awards the answer provider 15 rep points. Only 1 answer can be accepted. Once you reach 15 rep points you will have the privilege to up vote answers as well. You can up vote as many answers as you find useful, even answers to other people's questions. An up vote awards the answer provider 10 points.